Scala: minimal subset sum
Given a list of N positive integers.
The task is to print the size of minimal subset whose sum is greater than or equal to selected number (S)
For example:
Given:  4 8 10 12
For variants of S (for each test case):
  4
  13
  30
  100

Expected output: 1
2
3
For example, for S=13 there are many possible subsets of size 2 whose sum is not less than 13. They are {4, 10}, {4, 12}, {8, 10}, {8, 12} and {10, 12}.
My solution is:
   def subsetsSum(set: List[Int], targetValue: Int): Int = {
     @tailrec
     def subsetsSumHelp(upperLevelSet: List[Int]): Int = {
      val sum = upperLevelSet.sum
      if (sum > targetValue) subsetsSumHelp(upperLevelSet.tail) else upperLevelSet.size
    }

   val initialSum = set.sum
   if (initialSum < targetValue) -1 else subsetsSumHelp(set.tail)
  }

 val testCase = 13
 val input = List(4, 8, 10, 12)

 println(subsetsSum(input.sorted(Ordering.Int.reverse), testCase))

This done well. But I have some doubts, that it is the best solution. Particularly, the preliminary need for sorting confuses me.
May be there are other varianеs? For example some kind of binary search ?

You can avoid having to sort everything in many cases with https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/mutable/PriorityQueue.html

I don't see why you are removing elements from the front instead of the back.

Are you asking how to answer queries faster?

I remove the head elements, because input list is given in decreasing order

If you want the "size of minimal subset", then removing larger elements is not optimal.

One line solution: set.sorted(Ordering.Int.reverse).scanLeft(0)(_ + _).indexWhere(_ >= targetValue)

@esse That's not even close to a valid solution to the problem.
